# Unmet dependencies for ros desktop full

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, kde, ros

### Error

I'm trying to install the ros desktop full version on my pc following  [these steps](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu). Everything is all right until step 1.4, precisely

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

Where i'm given the following error:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-kinetic-desktop but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: ros-kinetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### Dependency tree

I'll report here the whole dependency tree, where i used the command `sudo apt-get install` for all the dependencies on the left of each list element.
I followed first the simulators dependency:

- ros-kinetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-kinetic-simulators
- ros-kinetic-simulators : Depends: ros-kinetic-rqt-common-plugins
- ros-kinetic-rqt-common-plugins : Depends: ros-kinetic-rqt-web
- ros-kinetic-rqt-web : Depends: ros-kinetic-webkit-dependency
- ros-kinetic-webkit-dependency : Depends: python-pyqt5.qtwebkit
- python-pyqt5.qtwebkit : Depends: python-pyqt5 (= 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build19) but 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build21 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Then i followed the desktop dependency:

- ros-kinetic-desktop : Depends: ros-kinetic-viz
- ros-kinetic-viz : Depends: ros-kinetic-rqt-common-plugins
- ros-kinetic-rqt-common-plugins : Depends: ros-kinetic-rqt-web
- ros-kinetic-rqt-web : Depends: ros-kinetic-webkit-dependency
- ros-kinetic-webkit-dependency : Depends: python-pyqt5.qtwebkit
- python-pyqt5.qtwebkit : Depends: python-pyqt5 (= 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build19) but 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build21 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

As you can see both point to the same package.
But when using

```
 sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5
```

I get

> python-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build21).

### What I've tried

1. Manually adding the following deb to */etc/apt/sources.list*

   ```
   deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse  
   deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   ```
2. Installing python-pyqt5 with `pip3 install pyqt5`
3. Using upgrade, update, dist-update multiple times with apt
4. Installing `ros-kinetic-ros-base`, which gave me no dependencies errors
5. Using `sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5=5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build19`
   Gives the following output before accepting installation:

   ```
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
   Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
   Investigating (0) python-pyqt5.qtsvg [ amd64 ] < 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build21 > ( python )
   Broken python-pyqt5.qtsvg:amd64 Depends on python-pyqt5 [ amd64 ] < 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build21 -> 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build19 | 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build21 > ( python )(= 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build21)
   Considering python-pyqt5:amd64 10002 as a solution to python-pyqt5.qtsvg:amd64 1
   Removing python-pyqt5.qtsvg:amd64 rather than change python-pyqt5:amd64
   Investigating (0) ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding [ amd64 ] < 0.3.3-0xenial-20171104-175930-0800 > ( misc )
   Broken ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding:amd64 Depends on python-pyqt5.qtsvg [ amd64 ] < 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build21 > ( python )
   Considering python-pyqt5.qtsvg:amd64 1 as a solution to ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding:amd64 0
   Removing ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding:amd64 rather than change python-pyqt5.qtsvg:amd64
   Investigating (0) ros-kinetic-rviz [ amd64 ] < 1.12.15-0xenial-20180105-172609-0800 > ( misc )
   Broken ros-kinetic-rviz:amd64 Depends on ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding [ amd64 ] < 0.3.3-0xenial-20171104-175930-0800 > ( misc )
   Considering ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding:amd64 0 as a solution to ros-kinetic-rviz:amd64 -1
   Removing ros-kinetic-rviz:amd64 rather than change ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding:amd64
   Done
   Suggested packages:
      python-pyqt5-dbg
   The following packages will be REMOVED:
      python-pyqt5.qtsvg ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding ros-kinetic-rviz
   The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
      python-pyqt5
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   Need to get 2.143 kB of archives
   ```

### More infos

I have the **KDE neon LTS 5.8** installed with the following specs:

- KDE Plasma Version: 5.8.8
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.42.0
- Qt Version: 5.7.1
- Kernel Version: 4.13.0-29-generic
- OS Type: 64-bit

Here I'll list every command i think it may be usefull followed by its output:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list 
deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial main

$ uname -a
Linux Ublion16 4.13.0-26-generic #29~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 9 22:00:44 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ apt-cache policy python-pyqt5
 python-pyqt5:
 Installed: 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build21
 Candidate: 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build21
 Version table:
 *** 5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build21 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user/lts xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build19 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user/lts xenial/main amd64 Packages
     5.8.2+dfsg-1+16.04+xenial+build13 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user/lts xenial/main amd64 Packages
     5.7+dfsg-3+16.04+build8 500
        500 http://archive.neon.kde.org/user/lts xenial/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4 500
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

Comment: KDE Neon is **not Ubuntu** and thus off topic on Ask **Ubuntu**.

Answer (score 0):

I just met a problem very similar to yours, but I solved it by adding

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe
```

to the head of /etc/apt/sources.list. Notice the "xenial" word in this sentence, it is supposed to be the same as your Ubuntu version.
If it doesn't work for you, I will advise you to remove the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list firstly and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Add following package sources to /etc/apt/sources.list.

```
deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse

deb-src http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Now, follow these steps from 1.2  in this [link](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list)

Comment: Those are simply the normal Ubuntu repository mirrors from the question. How would that help with the installation of this particular package from a different repository? -1